# SQL case with different fields to check from same table

Tags: sql, db2, case

I have  the following problem:
I have a select statement that includes a case part. Up til there it is easy the problem is that the case includes a check against another field in the same table.

```
    select h.id, 
    case h.value 
    when 'P' then 'test'
    when '' then 'failed'
    when 'D' then 'passed'
    else null end
    as info, 
    b.text, 
    case h.diag
    when h.value = ''  [or 'failed' not sure tried both and didn't work]
    else h.diag end
    as diag1, h.date from valuetab h, texttab b where h.id=b.id
```

I want to have h.diag only to show values when h.value is not failed.

I always get the mistake that the = should be concat.. but that doesn't make sense in my eyes.

Any ideas??

Thats for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also write a case statement with your expression in a different place i.e.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN X = 1 THEN 'Y' WHEN X = 2 THEN 'Z'
```

I think what you want to do is something more like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN h.value = '' THEN h.diag end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `THEN` portion of the `WHEN` clause, and specifying a condition where you could specify a value:

```
case h.value
when '' THEN NULL
else h.diag end
```

Comment: this is syntactically incorrect. When you specify an express in `CASE <expression>` you can have another expression in the `WHEN` just a value. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0005646.htm

Comment: @CodeMagician You're right, I spotted the missing `then`, but missed the conditional inside a "simple" WHEN clause that does not allow conditions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the other form of `case` statement, which doesn't specify a column you want to look at:

```
select case 
          when column1 = 2 then 'Foo'
          when other_column = 'blah' then 'Bar'
       end
    from table
```

The problem with using `case column1 when...` is that it implicitly compares `column1` to each `when` clause.  You can't then include a comparison to some other column in it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok got it....

after the 2nd case the "h.diag" must be removed....

so it is

```
    case 
    when h.value = ''  then null
    else h.diag end
    as diag1,
```